# Enable/Disable Click event for element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I want Enable/Disable click event on element. I have following code...

HTML:

```
<a id="CP" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">Current Processes</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#CP", function(event) {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function() {
        return false;
    });
    $this.html("Processing...").css({
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "cursor": "default"
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'abc.jsp',
        success: function(process) {
            //My code goes here...
            $this.on("click"); //  Here i want to bind or add handler which is fired previously.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: set `href="#"` and remove that `cursor: pointer` . You're using an `anchor` like a `div`

Comment: why do you want to do that? is it you only want to register the event once? if that is the case then you can use the `one` event http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand well, you could do that very simple with the following:

```
$this.html("Processing...").css({
    "cursor": "wait",
    "pointer-events": "none"
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 7):

Add some class when performing AJAX request. Remove when done. Do nothing if link has this class.

```
$(document).on("click", "#CP", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $a = $(this);
    if($a.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    $a.html("Processing...").addClass('disabled');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'abc.jsp',
        success: function(process) {
            $a.removeClass('disabled');

            // restore inner HTML here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this.on("click")` - this is effectively: "bind click handler to $this that will do nothing"

To trigger an event use: `$this.click()` or `$this.trigger("customEvent")`

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `bind("click")` so you can as well unbind it. e.g `$("#CP").bind("click",function(){..function to run // disable the click event from CP $("#CP").unbind("click"); });`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
var eventhandler = function() {

    $(document).unbind("click");
    $this.html("Processing...").css({
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "cursor": "default"
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'abc.jsp',
        success: function(process) {
            //My code goes here...
            //Here i want to bind or add handler which is fired previously.
            $(document).click(eventhandler); 
        }
    });
}


jQuery(document).click(eventhandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were faced with a common problem when you’re using **javaScript** to submit a form, the form data is submitted multiple times if the submit button is clicked multiple times. To solve this issue you only need to write one line code with help **CSS**.

```
document.getElementById("form1").style.pointerEvents="none";
```